# http url connection

Tags: java, android, json

Вот у меня есть код с парсингом json,мне надо, что бы json парсил с сервера
Как это сделать?

```
package my.home.page;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import org.json.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.util.*;

import my.home.page.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    String[] links, names;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        String json = "[{\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.vk.com\",\"name\":\"VK\"}, {\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.google.com\",\"name\":\"Google\"},{\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.yandex.ru\",\"name\":\"Yandex\"}]";
        try{
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
            int size = array.length();
            links = new String[size];
            names = new String[size];
            for(int n = 0; n < size; n++) {
                JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(n);
                links[n] = obj.getString("link");
                names[n] = obj.getString("name");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            Log.d("$", e.toString());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(links[position]));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вас сперва нужно получить json строку с сервера.

Иcпользуйте библиотеки [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) или [volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley).

Туториалы по [Retrofit](http://blog.zacorp.ru/mobile/ispolzovanie-retrofit-v-vashem-android-prilozhenii/) и [Volley](https://habrahabr.ru/post/188860/) на русском

**UPD:**

Без библиотек если хотите получить `json` строку, то вам нужно будет делать запрос асинхронно с помощью класса `AsyncTask` и для общения с сервером использовать `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: так как я нуб, как установить в Android studio?

Comment: обновил ответ..

Comment: json я получил, а без этих библиотек, ни как?

Comment: Можно и без библиотек. Что вы именно хотите? Получить json строку с сервера и распарсить или парсить уже вставленную вами json строку?

Comment: Получить строку и распарсить

Comment: на сервере тоже самое, что я вставил, только мне надо это теперь с сервера сдлеать

Comment: Вот с помощью этих библиотек можете легко получить строку и вставить вместо статичной json строки

Comment: Мне желательно без библиотек)

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: Спасибо,пошел изучать AsyncTask