# Парсить Json в android приложении

Tags: android

Есть файл json на сайте https://kavkaz.fm/info.json. Как парсить его и извлекать в коллекцию url и title ?

Comment: Вот посмотрите [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/603456/198423), отвечал(и) уже на этот вопрос много раз

Comment: Вот неплохой [пример](http://androiddocs.ru/parsing-json-poluchaem-i-razbiraem-json-s-vneshnego-resursa/)

Comment: Спасибо, буду читать и разбираться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала Вам нужно понять структуру Вашего Json. Для этого просто вставьте весь текст содержащийся в ссылке сюда http://json.parser.online.fr/ . После этого, уже когда будете иметь представление о конструкции, сможете распарсить его. Тут детально объясняет весь процесс парсинга http://androiddocs.ru/parsing-json-poluchaem-i-razbiraem-json-s-vneshnego-resursa/ .

Comment: Пишет что синтаксическая ошибка SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0 ((

Comment: Поставьте туда не ссылку на сайт https://kavkaz.fm/info.json, а его содержание.

Comment: Понял.. Содержимое файла json периодически меняется. Как можно динамически в приложении заново получать обновленное содержимое этого файла?

Comment: Ну если конструкция, имена объектов не меняются, то при смене самих данных Вам не придется ничего менять в своем коде.

Comment: Был рад помочь.

Comment: Все получилось! :) Но у меня вопрос мелкий, в самом json файле, к которому я доступа не имею чтобы редактировать кодировка title непонятная. Возможно ли в коде в нормальный русский язык перевести его?)

Comment: HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;    
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

Comment: ругается на метод setRequestProperty

Comment: И такой момент еще. Вот распарсил, получил что нужно и вывел в Textview в методе onCreate создал объект класса как в том примере. Затем данные изменилось в json, но в приложении не обновилось. Вот тут как обновлять?

Comment: Нужно написать метод, который через указанный интервал проверял, НО это загрузит ваше приложение.

Comment: Понял. А возможно ли получить конкретный объект не через индекс, а по одному из полей? Например в том файле, что я парсил есть у объекта поле name. Получить строку у которой поле name равно допустим "Грузинское радио"

Comment: JSONArray stations= dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("stations");
JSONObject name = stations.getJSONObject(3);

Comment: Думаю можно и по названию, но не знаю как это организовать

Comment: Ну ладно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
        JSONObject rootJson = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(json));
        JSONArray stationsJson =  rootJson.getJSONArray("stations");
        for (int i = 0; i < stationsJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject stationJson = stationsJson.getJSONObject(i);

            String title =  stationJson.optString("title");
            String url =  stationJson.getString("url");

            //Записывайте в любую коллекцию
            Log.d("TAG", "title =" + title + "; url = " + url );
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Используется метод `optString()`, потому что `title` есть не везде, при использовании `getString()` упадет JSONException если не найдет `title`.

Comment: не могли бы вы немного подробнее написать, что происходит в вашем кусочке кода?

Comment: И вам спасибо optString() помог!